# Getting user detail, when login from google in iOS application

Tags: ios

I am using google login in my project i have successfully login but did not got the user detail.
i have use code from this link
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in 
an fetch the value from 
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people

this code for login and getting user email id and circle people:

```
 [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientId;
//[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].scopes= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, nil];
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchGoogleUserID=YES;
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail=YES;
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].delegate=self;

[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];

GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
```

// [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];

```
GTLQueryPlus *query =
[GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
                                collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];
[plusService executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed,
                            NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
                // Get an array of people from GTLPlusPeopleFeed
                NSArray* peopleList = peopleFeed.items ;
                NSLog(@"People list =%@",peopleList);
            }
        }];
```

NSLog(@"email =%@", signIn .authentication.userEmail);
}

but get these error in console

BarberBlue[3611/0x1051a7310] [lvl=3] __27-[LoginVC loginWithgoogle:]_block_invoke() Error: Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.)" UserInfo=0x10c91cf90 {error=Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup., NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.), GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x10c91e490: {message:"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." data:[1] code:403}
}

Comment: have u got any answer for ur question . i m also facing same prob

Comment: @Imran sorry  i have not got any answer

Answer (score 2):

```
GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
[plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];
plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];

[plusService executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            GTLPlusPerson *person,
                            NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
                NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                         @"%@\n%@", person.displayName,
                                         person.name];
                NSLog(@"User Detail : %@" ,description);
            }
        }];
```

> I am also faced same problem, this method solved that. Using above code you will get the user detail.

Answer (score 1):

To get User Details do the following :

```
GTLPlusPerson *person = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].googlePlusUser;
    if (person == nil) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Person : %@" ,person);
```